# Problem with a Tkinter checkbox attribute. AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox

I would like to click the `selectall` checkbox, and automatically select all the checkboxes in the `cbs` list.

I'm getting this error: `AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'select'`

Reading on StackOverflow, I found similar questions, but the solution used doesn't work: `selectall.configure(state=NORMAL)`

What am I doing wrong? How to solve the problem? Thank you

```
    self.selectall = tk.IntVar()
    self.Checkbutton1 = tk.IntVar()
    self.Checkbutton2 = tk.IntVar()
    self.Checkbutton3 = tk.IntVar()

    cbs = [
        self.Checkbutton1,
        self.Checkbutton2,
        self.Checkbutton3,
        ]

    def function_select_all():
        for cb in cbs:
            cb.select()

    selectall = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Select All",
                                     variable=self.selectall,
                                     onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                     command= function_select_all())

#Example of Checkbox
   Checkbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbutton1",
                  variable=self.Checkbutton1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,   
                  command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton1.get(), partial(myfunction, self)))
   Checkbutton1.place(x=-2, y=69)
```

**UPDATE CODE (AFTER EDITING BY @Bryan Oakley)**

```
selectall_value = self.selectall.get() AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get'.
```

Code

```
    self.Checkbutton1 = tk.IntVar()
    self.Checkbutton2 = tk.IntVar()
    self.Checkbutton3 = tk.IntVar()

    def function_select_all():
        selectall_value = self.selectall.get()
        for checkbutton in self._checkbuttons:
            checkbutton_value = checkbutton.getvar(checkbutton.cget("variable"))
            if checkbutton_value != selectall_value:
                checkbutton.invoke()
    
    self._checkbuttons = [
        self.Checkbutton1,
        self.Checkbutton2,
        self.Checkbutton3,
        ]

    self.selectall = tk.IntVar()
    self.selectall = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Select all",
                                               variable=self.selectall,
                                               onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                               command= function_select_all)
    self.selectall.place(x=0, y=865)

#Example of Checkbox
   Checkbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbutton1",
                  variable=self.Checkbutton1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,   
                  command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton1.get(), partial(myfunction, self)))
   Checkbutton1.place(x=0, y=69)
```

Comment: The error obviously tells you that you cannot call `.select()` on an instance of tkinter `IntVar()`.  For you case, use `cb.set(self.select_all.get())` instead of `cb.select()`.  Also `command=function_select_all()` should be `command=function_select_all` (without the `()` after `function_select_all`).

Comment: @acw1668 Now they are selected automatically, but a strange thing happens: if I manually select all the checkboxes (by clicking on each one by one) then the checkboxes work correctly, while if I automatically select all the checkboxes with the question code, then they don't work

Comment: You should provide a [mre] including the creation of those checkbuttons.

Comment: I will update the code this evening with a minimal reproducible example, but in the meantime I can provide you with further useful information. I hope it can be useful to understand why the checkboxes are selected but do not work (while if selected manually they work). Each checkbox (Checkbutton1, Checkbutton2, Checkbutton3) is composed like this: command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton1.get(), partial(myfunction, self))). Can this information be useful to you?

Comment: *"if I automatically select all the checkboxes with the question code, then they don't work"* - What do you mean by *"they don't work"*? Does it mean that `clicked()` is not executed?

Comment: @acw1668 Exact. clicked() is not executed, but the rest of the command is not executed either. Whatever the functions of the checkboxes to be automatically selected (even if a checkbox contains a simple print), when I automatically select the checkboxes nothing happens. It is as if the command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton1.get(), partial(myfunction, self))) line was not executed. However, if I manually select the checkboxes, they work correctly and the command starts. Basically the checkboxes are selected, but are not "activated". Do you know how I could solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the root of the problem: you are trying to call `select()` on a variable rather than a checkbutton, and variables don't have a `select` method.

Since all of your checkbuttons use the same value for the selected state, you can call the `set` method of the variables to set the value:

```
def function_select_all():
    for cb in cbs:
        cb.set(1)
```

If you prefer to use the `select` method, then you need to iterate over the checkbuttons rather than the variables. You will need to hardcode the checkbuttons in a list, or hardcode the checkbuttons in the function.

```
def function_select_all():
    for cb in self._checkbuttons:
        cb.select()
...
self._checkbuttons = [Checkbutton1, Checkbutton2, Checkbutton3]
```

**If you want the command to be called when you change the checkbutton values**  you need to call `invoke` rather than `select`. According to the [canonical tcl/tk documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.13/TkCmd/checkbutton.htm#M26) *"Does just what would have happened if the user invoked the checkbutton with the mouse: toggle the selection state of the button and invoke the Tcl command associated with the checkbutton, if there is one. "*

It's important to know that `invoke` *toggles* the value. So if it was previously selected it will be unselected. If you want to make sure it only selects the checkbuttons that weren't already selected you'll need to test for that.

In the following example, instead of toggling each checkbutton when the "Select All" button is clicked, it instead toggles each checkbutton if it is different from the "Select All" button. In this way, selecting "Select All" will select all, and unselecting "Select All" will unselect all.

```
def function_select_all():
    selectall_value = self.selectall.get()

    for checkbutton in self._checkbuttons:
        checkbutton_value = checkbutton.getvar(checkbutton.cget("variable"))
        if checkbutton_value != selectall_value:
            checkbutton.invoke()
...
self._checkbuttons = [Checkbutton1, Checkbutton2, Checkbutton3]
```

However, that is not the only problem. You also need to make sure that the `command` associate with the "Select All" button is a command. You're making a common mistake of calling the command and passing the result to the `command` attribute. Instead, you need to set it to the actual command.

In the following example, notice how the value is `function_select_all` and not `function_select_all()`.

```
selectall = tk.Checkbutton(...,
                           command= function_select_all)
```

Comment: @Bryn Oakley Your answer is the same comment that acw1668 wrote. Aside from the function brackets, acw1668 had also suggested cb.set(1), later changed the comment to cb.set(self.select_all.get()). Both ways work. But there is a problem: as you can read in the comments with acw1668 (using cb.set(1) or cb.set(self.select_all.get())), the selected checkboxes don't work. They activate, but it is as if their relative command does not respond. However, if I manually select them one by one, they work correctly. Can you revise your answer please?

Comment: @Horiatiki: I've updated the answer. I apologize for not addressing the issue with calling the command. You'll need to use `invoke` rather than `select`, and you need to understand how the two are different.

Comment: I get the error: AttributeError: 'IntVar' object has no attribute 'getvar'. I know it will be something simple and trivial, but how can I solve it? Thank you

Comment: @Horiatiki: if you get that, you’re calling `getvar` from the variable instead of the checkbox. This is essentially the same error you originally asked about.

Comment: I'm using your code. You used getvar in selected = cb.getvar(cb.cget("variable")). Ok fine. Do I have to write getvar somewhere else too? (sorry for the questions, but I'm new to Python). Thank you

Comment: @Horiatiki Yes, but I used it with a checkbox, not a variable. `cb` in my code is a checkbutton. `getvar` is a method on a widget, not a variable. It takes a variable name as an argument.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Could you modify your code and show me an example? Thanks and sorry again. Maximum respect for you

Comment: There is a logical issue of your solution: if I check "Select All" and not selected checkbuttons will be checked (this is OK). However if I uncheck any of the checkbuttons and then uncheck "Select All", the unchecked checkbutton will be checked.

Comment: @acw1668: I've updated the answer to toggle the checkbuttons to match the value of the "Select All" button, so it either selects all or deselects all.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tested your new code. I get error: selectall_value = self.selectall.get() AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get'. How can I solve it? Thank you

Comment: @Horiatiki Based on your posted code in your question, you should not get this error because `self.selectall` is an instance of `IntVar` and `selectall` is the instance of `Ckeckbutton`.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, I know, it's weird. If you'd be so kind as to help me, I've updated my question and placed (below) the code I'm currently using after Bryan Oakley's suggestions. Can you understand why I get the error selectall_value = self.selectall.get() AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get'.? Thank you

Comment: @Horiatiki It is because you used same variable name `self.selectall` for both the `IntVar` and `Checkbutton`. And your updated code does not follow Bryan's solution.

Comment: @acw1668  Ok, now I've used two different names for both IntVarche and Checkbutton. I left the checkbox's self.selectall unchanged and unchanged.

Instead I changed the name of intvar, from self.selectall = tk.IntVar() to self.selectall_intvar = tk.IntVar().

Afterwards I also changed variable=self.selectall_intvar of the checkbox (otherwise I would have received the error AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'selectall'). I still get the same error as above: AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Horiatiki: you need to read the error messages, and try to understand what they are telling you. If you get `Checkbutton object has no attribute ...` that's telling you that you're trying to access an attribute on a Checkbutton that doesn't exist. So ask yourself either "why doesn't the attribute exist" or "why does it think it's a Checkbutton". You can solve these problems by reading the error and then examining your code. You are making assumptions about your code, and you need to verify those assumptions.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  I understand what the error message says, but I don't know what to fix. Your code confused me a bit and I can't fix the problem. It's a problem with your code after all, only you left out that part. In the code of my question, I show the checkbox I use, but you didn't put it in your answer. In your code could you add the part that gives me an error please? Thank you

Comment: @Horiatiki: there is no problem with the code I posted. It works fine.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  In your selectall = tk.Checkbutton(..., command= function_select_all), what did you write in variable=...?

Comment: @Horiatiki: the same thing that you did: `variable=self.selectall`. In your updated code you used `self.selectall` to mean two different things. You need to use a different variable to store the checkbutton.